# Which is the best way for programming GPIOs in FriendlyARM board mini2440?

Tags: c++, qt, linux-kernel, arm, gpio

I have a mini2440 board with Linux 2.6 on which I have to program to control a mounted solar panel. The algorithm is provided and I need to code it for the ARM board. The GUI is done in Qt and I need a to write the code for the actual control. I saw the method for GPIO access from user space and it is tedious. I question the accuracy I can get for PWM.

What other methods can I use to program the GPIOs for on/off and PWM applications?

A few friends suggested programming the control code as a kernel module but I am not quite sure I wish to jump into that.

Comment: There is a *PWM* infra-structure in Linux.  You need need to specify your problem a little more clearly.  What is the *PWM* frequency and duty cycles?  If the frequency is low (20Hz), you can do this from user space.  Probably there will be lots of jitter if you try to implement a *PWM* above this frequency.  Even `nice` tasks will have to give up time to the kernel tasks, etc.

Answer (score 4):

> A few friends suggested programming the control code as a kernel module but I am not quite sure I wish to jump into that.

I am almost certain if it is not closely hardware related it would be rejected in the Linux kernel. The purpose of the userspace syscall and sysfs access to put your custom logic into a Linux on top of the hardware abstraction (OSI model).

What you would need to do is first check if the Linux kernel provides all the hardware support for your devices. Then you could take my middleware class for controling the GPIO in a C++ manner. Finally, you could write a small main application to test the kernel and C++ class. That application would do just something simple like instantiating the GPIO class, export a GPIO, and then write values.

(How this is related to your PWM question is unclear, but you seem to mix up two different kernel driver areas)

You could do something like the code below through [sysfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt) as per the [Linux kernel gpio documentation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/gpio.txt). You will of course need to make sure that your hardware gpio is supported by the Linux kernel.

#### gpio.h

```
#ifndef FOOBAR_GENERALPURPOSEIO_H
#define FOOBAR_GENERALPURPOSEIO_H

namespace Foobar
{
   class FOOBAR_EXPORT GeneralPurposeIO
   {
       public:

           enum Direction {
               Input,
               Output
           };

           explicit GeneralPurposeIO(quint32 gpioNumber = 0);
           ~GeneralPurposeIO();

           int gpioExport();
           int gpioUnexport();
           bool isGpioExported();

           quint32 gpioNumber() const;
           void setGpioNumber(quint32 gpioNumber);

           Direction direction() const;
           int setDirection(Direction direction);

           qint32 value() const;
           int setValue(qint32 value);

       private:

           class Private;
           Private *const d;
   };
}

#endif // FOOBAR_GENERALPURPOSEIO_H
```

#### gpio.cpp

```
#include "generalpurposeio.h"

#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtCore/QFile>

using namespace Foobar;

class GeneralPurposeIO::Private
{
   public:
       Private()
       {
       }

       ~Private()
       {
       }

       static const QString gpioExportFilePath;
       static const QString gpioUnexportFilePath;
       static const QString gpioDirectionFilePath;
       static const QString gpioValueFilePath;
       static const QString gpioFilePath;

       quint32 gpioNumber;
};

const QString GeneralPurposeIO::Private::gpioExportFilePath = "/sys/class/gpio/export";
const QString GeneralPurposeIO::Private::gpioUnexportFilePath = "/sys/class/gpio/unexport";
const QString GeneralPurposeIO::Private::gpioDirectionFilePath = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%1/direction";
const QString GeneralPurposeIO::Private::gpioValueFilePath = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%1/value";
const QString GeneralPurposeIO::Private::gpioFilePath = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%1";

GeneralPurposeIO::GeneralPurposeIO(quint32 gpioNumber)
   : d(new Private)
{
   d->gpioNumber = gpioNumber;
}

GeneralPurposeIO::~GeneralPurposeIO()
{
}

/*
* Exports the desired gpio number.
*
* Note: Unfortunately, it is not possible to just call this method "export"
* since that is a reserved keyword in C++. Systematically the unexport method
* cannot be called "unexport" either for consistency.
*/

int GeneralPurposeIO::gpioExport()
{
   if (isGpioExported()) {
       // TODO: Proper error mutator mechanism for storing different error
       // enumeration values internally that can be requested by the API user

       qDebug() << "Cannot export the gpio pin since it is already exported:" << d->gpioNumber;
       return -1;
   }

   QFile gpioExportFile(d->gpioExportFilePath);
   if (!gpioExportFile.open(QIODevice::Append)) {
       qDebug() << "Cannot open the gpio export file:" << d->gpioExportFilePath;
       return -1;
   }

   /*
    * Seek to begining of the file
    */

   gpioExportFile.seek(0);

   /*
    * Write our value of "gpioPinNumber" to the file
    */

   if (gpioExportFile.write(QByteArray::number(d->gpioNumber)) == -1) {
       qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Error while writing the file:" << d->gpioExportFilePath;
       gpioExportFile.close();

       return -1;
   }

   gpioExportFile.close();

   return 0;
}

int GeneralPurposeIO::gpioUnexport()
{
   if (!isGpioExported()) {
       // TODO: Proper error mutator mechanism for storing different error
       // enumeration values internally that can be requested by the API user

       qDebug() << "Cannot unexport the gpio pin since it is not exported yet:" << d->gpioNumber;
       return -1;
   }

   QFile gpioUnexportFile(d->gpioUnexportFilePath);
   if (!gpioUnexportFile.open(QIODevice::Append)) {
       qDebug() << "Cannot open the gpio export file:" << d->gpioUnexportFilePath;
       return -1;
   }

   /*
    * Seek to begining of the file
    */

   gpioUnexportFile.seek(0);

   /*
    * Write our value of "gpioPinNumber" to the file
    */

   if (gpioUnexportFile.write(QByteArray::number(d->gpioNumber)) == -1) {
       qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Error while writing the file:" << d->gpioUnexportFilePath;
       gpioUnexportFile.close();

       return -1;
   }

   gpioUnexportFile.close();

   return 0;
}

bool GeneralPurposeIO::isGpioExported()
{
   if (!QFile(d->gpioFilePath.arg(d->gpioNumber)).exists()) {
       return false;
   }

   return true;
}

quint32 GeneralPurposeIO::gpioNumber() const
{
   return d->gpioNumber;
}

void GeneralPurposeIO::setGpioNumber(quint32 gpioNumber)
{
   d->gpioNumber = gpioNumber;
}

GeneralPurposeIO::Direction GeneralPurposeIO::direction() const
{
   // TODO: Implement me

   return GeneralPurposeIO::Output;
}

int GeneralPurposeIO::setDirection(Direction direction)
{
   if (!isGpioExported()) {
       if (gpioExport() == -1) {
           return -1;
       }
   }

   /*
    * Set the direction
    */

   QFile gpioDirectionFile(d->gpioDirectionFilePath.arg(d->gpioNumber));

   if (!gpioDirectionFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
       qDebug() << "Cannot open the relevant gpio direction file:" << d->gpioDirectionFilePath;
       return -1;
   }

   int retval = 0;

   /*
    * Seek to begining of the file
    */

   gpioDirectionFile.seek(0);

   switch (direction) {

   case Output:
       if (gpioDirectionFile.write("high") == -1) {
           qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Error while writing the file:" << d->gpioDirectionFilePath;
           retval = -1;
       }

       break;

   case Input:
       if (gpioDirectionFile.write("low") == -1) {
           qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Error while writing the file:" << d->gpioDirectionFilePath;
           retval = -1;
       }

       break;

   default:

       break;

   }

   gpioDirectionFile.close();

   return retval;
}

qint32 GeneralPurposeIO::value() const
{
   // TODO: Implement me

   return 0;
}

int GeneralPurposeIO::setValue(qint32 value)
{
   if (direction() != GeneralPurposeIO::Output) {
       qDebug() << "Cannot set the value for an input gpio pin:" << d->gpioNumber;
       return -1;
   }

   /*
    * Set the value
    */

   QFile gpioValueFile(d->gpioValueFilePath.arg(d->gpioNumber));
   if (!gpioValueFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
       qDebug() << "Cannot open the relevant gpio value file:" << d->gpioValueFilePath.arg(d->gpioNumber);
       gpioValueFile.close();
       return -1;
   }

   /*
    * Seek to begining of the file
    */

   gpioValueFile.seek(0);

   if (gpioValueFile.write(QByteArray::number(value)) == -1) {
       qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Error while writing the file:" << d->gpioValueFilePath.arg(d->gpioNumber);
       gpioValueFile.close();
       return -1;
   }

   gpioValueFile.close();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I had seen samples of your general purpose program and tried to write a C code for it myself. It gave some inconveniences like failure to create the specific files/folders at `/sys/class/gpio/` even if run by root user. Also I want to give PWM signal using these GPIO which is why I was asking if any other method exists which would make this easier.

Comment: First of all, you do not create files, but the class will do that for you. More importantly, you have not provided any concrete errors. I really have no idea why you keep mixing up the two. Tachometer, etc, are different to a togglable GPIO. Anyway, this class works fine for me and some other people. You may probably have bigger problems with your Linux kernel.

Comment: Quote: *How this is related to your PWM question is unclear, but you seem to mix up two different kernel driver areas*... You can implement a PWM by toggling a GPIO high/low in a fixed period.  I think you missed that idea.  This will load the system and requires some good system response to user space.

Comment: @artlessnoise: no, I did not. However, you seem to have missed that I eventually gave a complete gpio implementation in C++ for sysfs, so that part had been done a while ago. If you want anything more, this is _not_ related to GPIO, but since the OP's question was not all that clear, this is the best answer I could give.

Comment: I tried the code but it keeps failing to open/write files. I cannot access any files even when running the code as root user. Also I didn't understand what `FOOBAR_EXPORT` is. I even tried to modify permissions of every file in `/sys/devices/virtual/gpio/`.

Comment: @VedVals: it is possible that you are doing something wrong. If a file is accessible it must be opened. There is no other way around to it. :)

Comment: @VedVals: also, it is not /sys/devices/virtual/gpio, but /sys/class/gpio. Have you resolved it since then?

Comment: @LaszloPapp `/sys/slass/gpio/<whatever>` is a symbolic link to `/sys/devices/virtual/gpio/<same whatever>` except for `export` and `unexport` files. I can access it from pure c code but not from Qt

Comment: @VedVals: you should use the one I mentioned (/sys/class/gpio). I cannot say what the problem is because you have not shared the corresponding code just yet, nor the permissions, nor the error, etc.